# Shaded cells option in ot-tableau

Tags: shading

I am using the package ot-tableau to make OT tableaux and there is an option for shaded cells. In the package documentation, the cells appear as shaded but when I use the exact same code from the documentation the cells don't appear shaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[shadedcells]{ot-tableau}

\begin{document}

\begin{tableau}{c|c}
\inp{\ips{ba}} \const{*VcdObs} \const*{\textsc{Ident-IO}-[nas]}
\cand{ba} \vio{*!} \vio{}
\cand[\HandRight]{pa} \vio{} \vio{*}
\end{tableau}

\ShadingOn
\begin{tableau}{c|c}
\inp{\ips{ba}} \const{*VcdObs} \const*{\textsc{Ident-IO}-[nas]}
\cand{ba} \vio{*!} \vio{}
\cand[\HandRight]{pa} \vio{} \vio{*}
\end{tableau}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! See https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu. I recommend contacting `ot-tableau`'s author with a reference to the GitHub page. Compiling the documentation also omits shading. I don't know this is a `tabu` issue, but the state of that package makes it very likely. If it is a `tabu` issue, `ot-tableau`'s author could report it, but no package which depends on `tabu` can be recommended at present. Unfortunately, that means you'd be well advised to look for an alternative to `ot-tableau` unless the author plans to migrate from `tabu`.

Comment: The problem is the dashed lines for unranked constraints can be drawn with `tabu` or `arydshln`, but `tabu` conflicts with `colortbl`, and `arydshln` conflicts with `hhline`. It was working in 2017....

Answer (score 1):

This was an error caused by an incompatibility of `colortbl` and `tabu`. The current version (soon to be available on CTAN, and also on [GitHub](https://github.com/adamb924/ot-tableau) now) shades cells correctly. There is a trade-off (because of obscure package dependencies and conflicts) in that the lines of the tableau are not as pretty; hopefully the package conflicts will be resolved in the future.